# Can I get pageviews that don't have a value for a custom dimension in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get an overview of pageviews that don't have a value for my custom dimension.

The purpose is to figure out why only 70% of users actually seem to get a value assigned to this dimension, because I'm trying to get it as close to 100% as possible.

Here's a screenshot of a config I've tried so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try *Exclude* **Experiment-Header Version** *Matching RegExp* **user-unasigned|controll-a|controll-b**